# JavaScript/jQuery Pause function and then fire it again

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I've got a form where once a person clicks 'Submit' an Ajax is fired and `e.preventDefault();` is used so that the form doesn't actually submit.

My problem: I do want the form to be submitted to  the server but only after Ajax came back with success.

So as an example I am trying to achieve the following scenario:

- User clicks 'Submit'
- Ajax is fired sending some info, and the user remains on the page.
- Ajax has come back through and we can now fire it's `success:` function.
- The success function is fired and the `form data` on the site is submitted to the server.

The html:

```
   <form name="demoFiler" action="save/uploadCreate.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        //Some inputs, checkboxes radios etc.

        <input type="submit" name="submitHandler" id="submitHandler" value="Upload" class="buttonUpload hideButton" />

    </form>
```

The Javascript:

```
    document.getElementById(this.config.form).addEventListener("submit", submitMe, false);

    function submitMe(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();

    //Necessary vars for the 'data' defined here

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:this.config.uploadUrl,
        data:data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(rponse){
                         //This is where we need our Success function to SUBMIT the form using uploadCreate.php
        }
    });

    }
```

Comment: That's really not the right way to do things. Have the AJAX call either do all the work of the form, or return errors.  If the return indicates that the POST was successful, you can then reload the page to what would be the form target. Pausing the browser with a synchronous AJAX call is possible but generally considered a terrible user experience.

Comment: Hmm so just post everything through Ajax or uploadCreate.php and not partially through one or the other?

Comment: Yes. Another option is to forget AJAX and just post the form. That way you only do one HTTP request in either case, rather than 2 when you succeed. Note that it's risky to rely on the validity status of the form data remaining valid between two separate HTTP requests.

Comment: I need to use Ajax in this instance - as I've got non-form data that will be sent along with the form. (namely an image that gets drag/dropped into the browser window for upload). But I think it should be possible to retrieve all the values of the form and submit it along via Ajax, right?

Comment: Yes, you could submit all the form parameters via AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the button to a click event instead of the form submit event and then fire the `.submit` function on the form element in the `success` ajax callback.

```
$("#submitHandler").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   //Fill "data" variable
   var data = {};

   //set the url
   var url = "someurl";

   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:url,
    data:data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(rponse){
       //test rponse then do below.
       $("form[name=demoFiler]").submit();
    }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you’re using jQuery already, try something like:

```
$('#'+this.config.form).submit(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    e.preventDefault();

    //Necessary vars for the 'data' defined here

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:this.config.uploadUrl,
        data:data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(rponse) {
            // do something with rponse
            $this.off('submit').submit(); // unbind the handler and submit
        }
    });
}
```